# CakePHP SimpleTest - Controller Test vs. Web Test

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, cakephp, simpletest

I wish to test basic CRUD operations in CakePHP (1.3) using SimpleTest.
For example, I wish to add a new record, and make sure that I get an error message if validation fails and a new record if save goes well.
Is it better to write these tests as (1) Controller tests for the relevant action (e.g. add()), or as (2) Web Tests, using $this->post() or $this->setField()?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but still no answer so I'll give it a shot...

I believe that the first thing you need to do is separate your concerns better.  Right now what you're doing, at least to me, is a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)...meaning something ain't right!

How did I come to this conclusion?

Well, the question you asked and how you're answering it.  The question that you're asking is:

> "How should I test a **model's** functionality?"

Your answer:

> "Test it from the **controller** or the **view**"

So, the first thing I would do is setup a method in the appropriate model to do what you're wanting.  Write out the code that you think you need.  Save a record and return the appropriate values that you're looking for based off whatever conditional statements you come up with.

After that I'd setup some fixtures so you have some data to test against.  You can learn more about CakePHP fixtures and how to create them at the CakePHP manual, http://book.cakephp.org/view/1201/Preparing-test-data  *(In future projects I'd make the fixtures first, but that's just a personal preference)*

Once your fixtures are setup you can actually go ahead and test your new model method.  Testing models, in my opinion, is the easiest to test in CakePHP.  I won't go into the details here, only because the CakePHP manual, http://book.cakephp.org/view/1207/Testing-models, has a bunch of info about how to test models.

At this point you should have a properly unit tested model action and **concerns properly being separated**.

That being said if you're feeling super spunky and want your code tested from all angles then by all means, setup a controller test to ensure the action is performing correctly.  Setup a web test to ensure the whole package is working together.

First though, separate your concerns.

Comment: Many thanks for the informative answer. 
I do have tests for the models, but I wish to test that the entire process works properly, as there are some manipulations on the data before they are saved or displayed. 
I do not wish to spend time writing both controller tests and web tests - I'd be happy to learn which you think should be preferred.

Comment: If you want to make sure your app works together as a whole I would say all three.  Model, controller and web testing.  It's the only way to be even remotely secure in believing that your code is stable.  No tests == no stability